# how do I send ether from msg.sender to contact in solidity

Tags: solidity, address.transfer

in solidity, how do I send eth from the msg.sender to the contract? For learning purposes, I want to transfer eth from one address(msg.sender) to a contract.

thank you!

Comment: This is pretty broad. Which part are you having trouble with? Writing a contract that can accept ether? Or sending ether with a transaction? If the latter, are you writing code to do this? Or using a tool (if so which one)?

Comment: i would like to add a function in a contract in solidity that takes a parameter with the ether amount to send to the contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to mark the function as `payable`:

```
function myFunction() public payable {
    // msg.value will be the amount of ether sent
}
```

See https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/15/writing-a-contract-that-handles-ether/ for a more complete example.

Comment: thanks for the link! that helps a lot.  in my function i wrote this: `function deposit(uint256 amount)  public payable returns (uint256){
     return this.balance;
  } ` but the balance is returned as 0. what did i miss ?

Comment: the error was from the test code, the amount should not be in the parameter  but passed as a value.

Comment: In our sample code, we tend to have the amount in both places (the value attached to the transaction as well as a parameter to the function) to mitigate mistakes by developers/users.

Comment: yes, that's a good way to make it more explicit during the call.